# Change the selected item

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jeditorpane

I have a `JEditorPane` and when I press ctr + space it makes visible a `JScrollPane` but because the editor pane is still selected is there any way to set the selected Item to be another?

(Selected is when you press a `JTextArea` and you can edit it so is selected the text area.)

Like I want to when I press ctr + space it appears the scroll pane and it selected so I just need to press an arrow to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call requestFocus() on the JComponent you want "selected".

Edit: From the documentation for JComponent#requestFocus:

> Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of requestFocusInWindow(boolean).

So maybe give requestFocusInWindow() a try as well.

Comment: *"So maybe give requestFocusInWindow() a try as well."* That should be the *first* (& *only*) thing to do.